# Get all select in table and replace them with their option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I've got a table and I would like to change every select with it's options.

So for example if the table has this :

```
<td>
    <select>
        <option>first option</option>
        <option selected>second option</option>
        <option>third option</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

It should become this :

```
<td>
    second option
</td>
```

Here's what I've tried :

```js
$('#table select').find(":selected").each(function() {
  this.replaceWith(this.text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <table id="table">
    <thead>
      <th>test</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option>first option</option>
            <option selected>second option</option>
            <option>third option</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option>first option</option>
            <option>second option</option>
            <option selected>third option</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

But I get a `this.text is not a function`, how can I point out to the text of the select items? I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

You figured out that the `this` keyword refers to the element selected. But `text` is a jQuery function and not present as a method on `this`.

To be able to use `this` and jQuery you need to wrap it into `$(this)`
. Use `parents` to select the `TD` and then change with `text`.

This should get the desired result as provided by your example.

```js
$('#table select').find(":selected").each(function() {
  $(this).parents("td").text($(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <table id="table">
    <thead>
      <th>test</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option>first option</option>
            <option selected>second option</option>
            <option>third option</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option>first option</option>
            <option>second option</option>
            <option selected>third option</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**Vanilla solution (without jQuery)**

```js
//Vanilla solution
//Array.from: casts a node list (array like) to actual Array; supported by all major browsers except IE
//querySelector is used to select the elements. Then loop with array's forEach
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#table select > option:checked")).forEach(function(element) {
  //element refers to the selected element
  //go up two elements to the TD and save to parent
  var parent = element.parentElement.parentElement;
  //use replaceChild and createTextNode
  //createTextNode creates a node from the string provided.
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(element.textContent);
  
  //replace from the parent
  parent.replaceChild(textNode, parent.querySelector("select"));
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table id="table">
    <thead>
      <th>test</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option>first option</option>
            <option selected>second option</option>
            <option>third option</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option>first option</option>
            <option>second option</option>
            <option selected>third option</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```